# Can't click on Google search button

Tags: c#, watin

I tried clicking on the google search button using [watin](http://watin.org/) after I wrote text into the search field:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("weather usa", "weather (.*)");
browser.GoTo("www.google.com");
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("weather:" + match.Groups[1].Value);
browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnK")).Click();
```

The application just freezes after correctly filling the text field. What should my next step be to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Is an exception thrown?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, no exceptions at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be caused by Google's auto complete functionality.

Google's home page with nothing typed in the search bar:

[image: Google's home page with nothing typed in the search bar]

Google after typing in the search bar, triggering auto complete:

[image: google auto complete]

Notice that the layout changes. The button whose name is `btnK` still exists on the page but is invisible. The search button visible to the user is now different: `btnG`.

You need to do one of the following:

- Click on `btnG`

  ```
  browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("weather:" + match.Groups[1].Value);
  browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();
  ```
- Set the value of the search box instead of typing and click on `btnK`.

  ```
  browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).Value = "weather:" + match.Groups[1].Value;
  browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnK")).Click();
  ```